# Group and count the same value in differents fields

Tags: mysql, sql

My English is bad so I show you an example of what I need.

Table with these columns:

```
id | name1 | name2
```

I need to transform the result of these two queries in one

```
SELECT name1, COUNT(name1) as a
FROM partidos
GROUP BY name1
ORDER BY a DESC;

SELECT name2, COUNT(name2) as b
FROM partidos
GROUP BY name2
ORDER BY b DESC;
```

The result is 'a + b', I need this sum in one query.

**Example:**

```
1 | james | carolina
2 | carolina | rupert
3 | mordor | james
4 | carolina | mordor
5 | paul | carolina
```

**Result:**

```
carolina 4
james 2
mordor 2
rupert 1
paul 1
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of "names" in `name1` and `name2`, then use `union all`:

```
select name, count(*)
from ((select name1 as name
       from partidos
      ) union all
      (select name2 as name
       from partidos
      )
     ) p
group by name
order by count(*) desc;
```